# my ascii to binary converter that i wrote in C++ displays binary backwards, how can i make it display right?

Tags: c++, string, binary, decimal, ascii

Ok so I wrote a ascii to binary converter in C++, everything is great, the only issue is that it displays the binary backwards, I don't know how to go about and display it right.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    getline(cin, word);

    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        int v = int(word[i]);
        while (v != 1 || 0) {
            int m = v % 2;
            cout << " " << m << " ";
            v = v / 2;
        }
        cout << " " << v;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So this is what I mean. When I run the code it asks for your input which is the ascii, so i input:

```
 f
```

Which is 102 in decimal, hence it should display:

```
 1100110
```

Instead i get:

```
 0110011
```

What do i do?

Comment: Instead of printing, you could simply store the representation either in another `int` or a `std::string`, then `reverse` it and finally display. By the way `while(v!=1||0)` is equivalent to `while(v!=1)`. Whatever `OR`ed with `0` (`false`), will convert to the first argument

Comment: How about putting your cout<< in a loop and iterate from last index to first??  Looks like you have done everything you need to answer your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code, a *bit mask* is used to isolate the bit.  The text form of the bit is then printed.  The bit mask is then rotated in the appropriate direction.

```
const size_t length = word.length();
for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    char bit_mask = 0x80;
    const char value(word[i]);
    for (size_t bit_count = 0; bit_count < 8; ++bit_count)
    {
       char bit_value = value & bit_mask;
       if (bit_value)
       {
          std::cout << '1';
       }
       else
       {
          std::cout << '0';
       }
       bit_mask >>= 1;
    } 
    std::cout << ' ';
}
```

The above code prints bits in *Most Significant Bit* format.  To change the bit order, change the initial value of the `bit_mask` and rotate the `bit_mask` left.

Comment: Ok i entered this: [link](https://ghostbin.com/paste/g2eyp)

i entered f and got 01111111

Comment: Try changing the data types from `char` to `unsigned char`.  On your system, `char` may be signed, which kind of messes things up (because the right shift will fill with ones if the bit_mask is signed).